# In the US, how to interpret the capital gains tax brackets

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax

This is a question about the United States tax code, and in particular about the demarcation between brackets for long term capital gains.  I recognize that the specific cutoffs and tax rates are subject to change.

I think my question will be clearer if I construct an example.  So:

Let's take it as given that for a single taxpayer, the highest capital gains rate is 20% , and this kicks in at $441,450.  Let's suppose that I am that single taxpayer, that I have ordinary income of $100,000, and that I have a long term capital gain of $600,000.

Which of the following scenarios is correct (ignoring all sorts of minutiae like adjusting for qualified dividends, etc.)?

a)  Of that $600,000, $158,550 (the excess of my capital gain over $441,450) is taxed at 20%.

b)  Of that $600,000, $258,550 (the excess of my capital-gain-plus-income over $441,450) is taxed at 20%.

c)  None of the above.

Comment: If I come back to it I'll make an answer of filling it out, but page 16 of the IRS instructions for Schedule D has a worksheet that you can fill out to answer your question: https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040sd.pdf

Comment: Also keep in mind the [Net Investment Income Tax](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/questions-and-answers-on-the-net-investment-income-tax) which will effectively make 20% approach 23.8%.

Comment: @Craig W :  Yes, I'm aware of this, though it was among the minutiae I chose to abstract away from.  Thanks for making sure I remembered it, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is (b), with a few caveats. Your marginal rate for capital gains starts at the bracket based on your *taxable* (not *ordinary*) income. So if your taxable income *after deductions* is $100k, then your math for option (b) is correct.  When your taxable income plus capital gains hits the bracket threshold, the remaining capital gains are taxed at that marginal rate.

So $341,450 of your capital gains are taxed at the rate below 20% (e.g. 15% in 2021 for single filers), and $258,500 of your capital gains are taxed at 20%.

Comment: Thanks.  This is very clear. Unless someone chimes in to say it's completely wrong, I expect I'll soon accept it.